# Why fitting $\mathbb{Q}$ vs $\mathbb{P}$ measure Heston model if both fit to market

Tags: option-pricing, risk-neutral-measure, heston, numeraire

If both models fit their closed form formulas to market prices, why should I prefer a more complex model? ($\mathbb{Q}$ version has one extra parameter $\lambda$)

Do valuation with dynamics work better under the $\mathbb{Q}$-measure version?

Comment: Most practitioners don't really look at the market price of risk. So they assume exactly the same form of the Heston model under P as under Q, except in the latter the parameters are calibrated to options prices, and in the former to historical time series of the stock. Hence, no added complication under Q.